# Parent in maven is rewrited

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, url-rewriting, parent

Hellou, i create classic pom in Java like New project-maven

```
<groupId>learn.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>multimodul</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

After i want create his parent POM, i choice achretype-webapp and build it, after i create it, my code is good

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>multimodul</artifactId>
        <groupId>learn.maven</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

but for 10seconds after building command my parent lookslike

```
<groupId>learn.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>web</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
```

and my parent was rewrited via Java idea
Its this automaticli rewrite ok? cause i lost my parent after

Comment: I have never heard of an IDEA rewritting a POM file.  I suggest you run mvn clean install from the terminal window, and see if you face such an issue?

Comment: The archetype-webapp is not suitable for a parent POM.

Comment: Yap problem was in webapp is not suitable,but maybe lowest  version was right,cause i folowing one old video a there he create simply webapp archetype and was simply Parent. So if i want upload my text on localhost without making war file,like mvn tomcat7:run  must make Main pom like webbapp and others simply poms without archetype?   Btw if have tomcat 9, is normal use command "mwn tomcat7:run" ?